# Content query web part issue

Tags: sharepoint, migration, web-parts, content-query-web-part

I have a content query web part in sharepoint 2013, where there are two lists using the same content type.

Nevertheless, one list was initially created using sharepoint 2010 and then **migrated** in to 2013.
The list that was migrated cannot be added in to the `content query web part`.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: How can a list be used as a site template?

Comment: What happens when you try to add the list to your CQWP?

Comment: It doesn't display the items which are rendered through the migrated list.